# shutil.move conditional errors

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, notepad++

I have a short python script (called VaultTransferScript.py) that should transfer a zip file from one machine to another. The destination machine is a mapped network-attached-storage machine, which I have assigned to be the Z: drive. 
The script is:

```
import shutil
import os
from datetime import datetime
time_stamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M')
title_str = 'VaultBackup.zip'
name = time_stamp + title_str 
shutil.move('C:\\Users\\Hawking\\Desktop\\VaultBackups\\MyBackup.zip', 
    os.path.join('Z:\\VaultBackups\\'+name))
```

I can run this script from the notepad++ run facility, using

```
cmd /C  python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

But running it in a batch script as:

```
echo off
C:\Users\Hawking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\Hawking\Desktop\VaultBackupTransfer.py
```

results in this:

```
C:\Users\Hawking\Desktop>echo off
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\Hawking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 557, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Hawking\\Desktop\\VaultBackups\\MyBackup.zip' -> 'Z:\\VaultBackups\\2018-09-21_14_30VaultBackup.zip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hawking\Desktop\VaultBackupTransfer.py", line 7, in <module>
    shutil.move('C:\\Users\\Hawking\\Desktop\\VaultBackups\\MyBackup.zip', os.path.join('Z:\\VaultBackups\\'+name))
  File "C:\Users\Hawking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 571, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Hawking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Hawking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Z:\\VaultBackups\\2018-09-21_14_30VaultBackup.zip'
```

WHat is the difference in how I invoke the python script, and why does it error out from the batch script, but not notepad++?

Comment: `os.path.join('Z:\\VaultBackups\\'+name)` -> `os.path.join('Z:\\VaultBackups', name)` or even `os.path.join('Z:', 'VaultBackups', name)`

Answer (score 2):

You might be running the Python program with different user permissions in Notepad++ versus the command prompt. Alternatively, another Python VM might be used. Although, nothing in particular makes me think that the later is true.

Comment: I always have this problem- It seems I don't have the points to formally accept an answer. I did upvote it